# How to Detect and Solve Tab Order Conflicts

Tags: c#, winforms

It is possible to assign the Tab Index to different controls.
That creates a conflict in tab ordering.
Is there a way to detect such conflict?
Is there a tool to reset the form's entire Tab Order?

```
control1.TabIndex = 17;
control2.TabIndex = 17;
```

Comment: View → Tab Order

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tab Index in Windows Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/314392/tab-index-in-windows-forms)

Comment: I'm afraid not. I have more yhen 20 controls on m form. This way, I'll have to go to each one and check the tab order manually. I can also open the designer file, and find conflict there. I was wondering about a tool